# How to structure a partial REST response, due to failed authorization?

Tags: api, rest, response, partial, unauthorized

Given my API response:

```
{
    "public_field1": "value1",
    "public_field2": "value2",
    "auth_required_field": "secret"
}
```

I'm wondering what are some strategies to use to indicate that the response contains partial data due to failed authorization.

Initially I was just going to just remove the field from the response, but ideally, the client would have some sort of indication that the response could not be displayed in full due.

Here are some ideas I've considered:

- Returning a HTTP 206 (very unlikely, since the intent is completely different from the use case).
- Just removing the field, and leaving the client to fend for itself.
- Removing the field, and adding a custom header (X-Failed-Authorization: more specific details?)

Answer (score 0):

My personal filling is that you should not say to the user that there is some hidden field that is available only when authenticate and authorized. Otherwise it might be a security issue.

Also I do not see a use case where a non authorized user would need to know if there is some hidden field.